# Sonar - Regexp for permissions

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any way to create a regexp for projects in sonar? For example, i want to give group 1 access to all the projects that are "DevelopXXXX", and group2 access to all the projects that are "ReleaseXXXX"

Thanks

Comment: As Ann say in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327583/how-to-apply-project-template-to-existing-projects-in-sonarqube play with templates

Comment: Yeah, what he said. :D